# Google analytics; Short setup Q

Tags: html, linux, security, google-analytics

I have just added the code to my index.html and uploaded the file. But Google Analytics Status says the code is not installed (not found).

I have a VPS (own server) which I manage myself.

Thing is, in my case, I have a setup like this:

```
  IP adress at a VPS provider
  Domain name at an ISP
  A-Pointer to point my domain to my IP adress
```

I am still learning so if somebody could explain if I need to setup GA in a special way for it to work I would appreciate it.

Currently in the section where you chose what type of code you want, I chose "standard, for a domain". But there are other options as well (for subdomains, top-domains etc)...

Hope somebody knows how to set it up.
Thanks

PS: I have apache authentication on my website currently, but I don't think this is interferring or is it?

Comment: Inspect using Firebug or Webkit Inspector. If you're requesting __utm.gif from Google Analytics, the data will send to Google just fine, as long as you pasted the correct tracking code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **just** added the code Google will say that, it takes time. Give it a day and if it still says that then i would start worrying.

Answer (score 0):

Google can't see your pages if they require authentication.

Comment: This is only true for any crawling validation scripts, but not true for its actual ability to track traffic data.